# Count groups by condition in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

The formular in my (inner) group footer looks like:

```
IIF( SUM({tbl.field1}, {groupA}) > 23 and SUM({tbl.field2},{groupA}) > 50, "OKAY", "NOT OKAY")
```

This prints for each (inner) group if the group is "OKAY" or "NOT OKAY". The outer group footer should count how many inner groups are "OKAY" and "NOT OKAY". So the output should look like:

```
GROUP1-HEADER
   GROUP2-HEADER
      REC
      REC
   GROUP2-FOOTER: "OKAY"
   GROUP2-HEADER
      REC
      REC
   GROUP2-FOOTER: "NOT OKAY"
GROUP1-FOOTER: 1x "OKAY, 1x "NOT OKAY".
```

The problem is, that I can't use the formular (from group2-footer) to calculate the count. My idea was to use a running total, counting the formular on each group2-change. But the formular isn't listed in the formular selection for running totals.

I'm using CR-XI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling we have overcomplicated things but you can do this using a running total:

set the field to summarize as the primary key of group2
set the summary type to distinct count
set the evaluation formula to: `SUM({tbl.field1}, {groupA}) > 23 and SUM({tbl.field2},{groupA}) > 50`
set the reset to on change of group1

I have attached a sample (look at the running total): http://tickett.net/downloads/13527881.rpt